# radius of nth circle inside a circle of given radius

Tags: geometry, circles, packing-problem

A circle of radius 100 cm is given. The goal is to place 7 circles of unequal radius inside the initial circle, so that each 3 of circles don't overlap each other and all of them stay inside the initial circle.
The first smaller circle is of radius 50 cm and so on.

I thought it has to do something with Ford circles, but answer r = 14.36 cm for the 7th circle is incorrect.

[image: Picture given for the problem]

Comment: see [appollian gasket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket), in particular the one $(-1,2,2,3...)$ in section "[integral appollonian circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket#Integral_Apollonian_circle_packings)".

Comment: when you say "7 circles of unequal radius", does that allow the first 2 circles to have equal radius (as suggested by eye-balling your pic)?

Comment: Yes, it allows that first two circles are of equal radius. I call them "unequal" to state that problem differs from packing circle with 7 circles of equal radius.

Comment: Well, it seems that curvature of 7th circle is 23, so, to clarify, if curvature is k = 1 / r, does that mean that r = 1 / 23, or 100 / 23 = 4.35 cm, as the initial circle has radius R = 100 cm.

Comment: The radii $(r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_7)$ are $\left(\frac{100}{2},\frac{100}{2},\frac{100}{3},\frac{100}{6},\frac{100}{11},\frac{100}{18},\frac{100}{\color{red}{27}}\right)$. In general, for $n \ge 2$, $r_n = \frac{100}{2+(n-2)^2}$. In addition to the integral apollonian circle packing I mentioned before, see [Pappus chian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus_chain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

[image]

One way is to consider
this construction as a part of the (infinite)
Steiner’s chain of circles defined by two circles,
$\bigcirc O((0,0), R)$ and $\bigcirc o((-r,0),r)$,
with the distance between their centers $d=r$,
where $R=100,\ r=50$.
The other $6$  circles $\bigcirc O_0,\dots,\bigcirc O_5$
are sandwiched between the two,
starting with $\bigcirc O_0((r,0),r)$.

All tangent points of the kissing circles in the chain
are located on the circle (shown green in the picture) centered at $X$ with radius
$r_x=|XO_i|$, $i=0,\dots,5$,

\begin{align} 
r_x&=
\sqrt{rR-\frac{rRd^2}{(r+R)^2}}
=\frac{200}3\approx 66.7
,
\end{align}

while all the centers $O_i$, $i=0,\dots,5$,
belong to the ellipse (shown yellow in the picture)
focused at $o,\,O$.

---

**Edit:**

Using [Descartes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem),
for the curvatures
$k_1,k_2,k_3,k_k$
of four mutually tangent circles,
\begin{align} 
k_4&=k_1+k_2+k_3\pm 2\sqrt{k_1 k_2+k_2 k_3+k_3 k_1}
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

In this particular arrangement of circles,
\begin{align} 
k_1&=-\tfrac1R
,\quad k_2=\tfrac2R
,\quad k_3=k_2=\tfrac2R
\end{align}

since each next circle in the chain is smaller,
the sign in \eqref{1} would be always positive
and we have

\begin{align}
k_4&=\tfrac3R
,\\
k_5&=\tfrac{6}R
,\\
k_6&=\tfrac{11}R
,\\
k_7&=\tfrac{18}R
,\\
k_8&=\tfrac{27}R
,
\end{align}

so the radii of
$\bigcirc O_i$, $i=1,\dots,5$
can be found as

\begin{align}
r_i&=\frac R{i^2+2}
.
\end{align}

For example, the seventh inner circle, the smallest one,
must have the radius

\begin{align}
r_5&=\frac R{27}
\approx 3.7037
.
\end{align}